# C++ Boost Property Tree Update Existing Node By Attribute Qualifier

Tags: c++, boost-propertytree

Ok, so here's a sample of the XML structure:

```
<config>
  <Ignored>
    <Ignore name="Test A">
       <Criteria>
          <value>actual value</value>
       </Criteria>
    </Ignore>
    <Ignore name="Test B">
       <Criteria>
          <value>actual value</value>
       </Criteria>
    </Ignore>
  </Ignored>
<config>
```

I would like to be able to do two things:

1. Perform a get directly to the Test A element without having to loop all Ignore elements..like a selector on an attribute.
2. If nothing else, I need a method of updating either of the Ignore elements and can't seem to figure it out

Do I have to delete the element and recreate it?  I can't seem to figure out a way to perform a put which qualifies an element (where there a many with the same name at the same level) by an attribute (which would be unique at that level).

Something like:

```
pt.put("config.Ignored.Ignore.<xmlattr>.name='Test A'.Criteria.value",some_var)
```

Or anything else that can achieve the end goal.  Thank you very much!

Full disclosure: I'm pretty new to C++ and may be missing something blatantly obvious.

Comment: Is there a good reason that you're using boost property tree for this? You may be better off using a real XML library instead.

Comment: Honestly?  No can't say I have a good reason.  I happened to have boost and figured I'd try to use what was there, and it's worked fine..until getting to this issue.  If you were to recommend a real XML library, what would it be?

Comment: I'd recommend tinyxml and libxml2 (depending on your other needs).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boost.property_tree xml parser (RapidXML) doesn't support this.
Consider using something like TinyXPath is you want such functionality out of the box.

Or use explicit loop to find `Ignore` node with required attribute. Then you can use

```
someIgnoreNode.put("Criteria.value", some_var);
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was trying to do when I posted the question, I think I'm missing something.

`BOOST_FOREACH(const ptree::value_type &v2, pt.get_child("config.Ignored")) {
if(_stricmp( cText, v2.second.get("<xmlattr>.name","").c_str() ) == 0 )
{
 BOOST_FOREACH(const ptree::value_type &v3, v2.second) {
  if(v3.first == "Criteria"){
   v3.second.put("value", szValue);
  }
 }
}`

But I get this error:
`cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<Key,Data>' to 'boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<Key,Data> &' `

Like I said, it's probably something stupid.

Comment: @CapersL, you are trying to modify `const` object - remove `const` from both `v3` and `v2` types

Comment: You see, I knew it would be something REALLY stupid!  As I said, I'm just a C++ n00b who was using example snippets, not really understanding what they were doing.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

you may use a method like:

```
auto & pt_child = pt.getchild("config.Ignored");
BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &v1, pt_child)
{
    if (v1.first == Ignore && v1.second.get<std::string>("<xmlattr>.name") == "Test A")
    {
        ptree & ptGrandChild = v1.second;
        ptGrandChild.put<std::string>("Criteria.value", some_var);
    }
}

boost::property_tree::xml_writer_settings<std::string> settings = 
boost::property_tree::xml_writer_make_settings<std::string>('\t', 1);
write_xml(xmlPath, pt, std::locale(), settings);
```